# Mousemove event gives error while using touch screen or stylus

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am working on whiteboard concept, where user may use mouse/style for writing on whiteboard. My app works fine if I write from mouse, but gives following error when i user stylus or touch screen.

Error: [Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive. See `https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5093566007214080`

I have user `{passive: true}`, still error persist.

Comment: Have you tried touch events ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events

Comment: I tried using touchevents. But it gives same error message when write using touch screen.